# Batch file - Loop through letters to set variables

Tags: for-loop, batch-file

I'm working on a batch file that sets the variables a through z and the default value should be y (for y or n).
I can't find a way to loop through all the letters and set them all to "y"
do loop a-z set=y

Currently, using

```
set a=y
set b=y
set c=y 
echo.&echo.&echo Do you want to:
set /P a=Set a RESTORE point? Y/N?....
set /P b=Disable Search and Prefetch? Y/N?....
set /P c=Close all running programs? Y/N?....
```

Comment: Any reason you want to preset the variables instead of taking the traditional approach of having the script act on the value of the variable after the fact?

Comment: `FOR %%G IN (A B C D E F etc....) DO set "%%G=Y"`

Answer (score 1):

The standard way:

```
for %%v in (a b c d e ... x y z) do set "%%v=y"
```

The smart-and-tricky way:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /L %%i in (97,1,122) do (
   cmd /C exit /B %%i
   set "!=ExitCodeAscii!=y"
)
```